# How do I properly use the sub function of regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have a number like `7.50x`, which I want to convert to `7.5x`. I thought about using regular expressions. I can easily match this expression, for example by using `re.search('[0-9].[0-9]0x', string)`. However, I'm confused how to replace every such number using the `re.sub` method. For example what should be there as the second argument?

```
re.sub('[0-9].[0-9]0x', ?, string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'([0-9]\.[0-9])0x', r'\1x', num)
```

**Test**

```
>>> import re
>>> num="7.50x"
>>> re.sub(r'([0-9]\.[0-9])0x', r'\1x', num)
'7.5x'
```

- `r'\1x'` here `\1` is the value saved from the first capturing group, `([0-9]\.[0-9])`

  eg for input `7.50x` the capturing group matches `7.5` which saved in `\1`

Comment: Can you explain what does r'\1x' really mean?

Comment: @MetallicPriest I have edited the answer. Hope its clear for you

Comment: That is awesome. Thanx for the answer. I think putting parantheses around [0-9].[0-9] is must here, so that it can be seen as first element \1. From this, I also infer that indexing for captured groups start from 1 rather than 0. Right?

Comment: @MetallicPriest You are awesome !!! The capturing group is those enclused in paranthesis. and off course they begin with 1. Also they are numbered from left to right. Hope you got that too :)

Comment: You must need to escape the dot.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You got that !! Thank you :) Corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
0+(?![1-9])(?=[^.]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/14

```
x=7.50x
re.sub(r"0+(?![1-9])(?=[^.]*$)","",x)
```

Comment: My question was not how to search it, but how to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Using positive lookahead and lookbehind assertion.

```
>>> import re
>>> num="7.50x"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d\.\d)0(?=x)', r'', num)
'7.5x'
```

- `(?<=\d\.\d)`, the number which precedes the digit `0` would be in this digit dot digit format.
- And the character following the match (`0`) must be `x`
- `\.` Matches a literal dot.